# shortcode using multiple WP_Query's with multiple category names not fully functional

Tags: wp-query, shortcode, query

we're working on a bilingual site,

[Larry A. Downs](http://www.larryadowns.com.php5-1.dfw1-2.websitetestlink.com/)

all the posts are categorized into two categories, english or spanish, along with other categories. so every post has multiple categories,

i've coded out a shortcode that sets up a tabbed widget in the sidebar, based on the language category, using multiple WP_Query's and looping thru them,

but if you look on the english category page: /category/english

some the queries are returning posts from the spanish category, 
i've checked the posts and they're in the right categories, 
i think i'm not setting up my query $args properly, and could use the wisdom of higher lever wordpressers than i.

thanks again stack.

here's the sidebartabs shortcode:
[SidebarTabs Shortcode](http://pastebin.com/sxn82WXx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of WordPress 3.6 you can put comma-delimited entries in the category_name property of the arguments array like this:

```
$args = array(
  'category_name' => 'news2014,news2015',
);

query_posts($args);
```

This works if the categories are both at the root level (no parent)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `category__and` and pass an array of category ids for language and favorites or language and lifestyle.

See [Category Paremeters for WP_Query in Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)

Comment: well that makes sense. i had thought $query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=staff,news' ); would do that. apparently not. tyty. so you can't do posts in multiple categories based on category name? no worries. guess i should have read a little further down the page... thanks for the help milo!

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly defining your category names as an array works, at least as of this date and WP 3.5.1-

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query(' category_name=array(staff,news) '); ?>
```

Comment: Would be better to not use a query string to add arguments. They're officially no longer supported by WP core (while still working) and won't be implemented for newer API functions.